# Object is merging with array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io, javascript-objects

I am emitting a socket on server side

socket.emit('foundUsers',currentUser,otherUsers)

otherUsers is a array of objects not containing currentUser object.

currentUser is a object similar to object structure of otherUsers but contains 2-3 extra parameters.

As a user i always receive object of currentUser.It is never empty.There is not problem in currentUser.
If there are no other users, i receive an empty array of otherUsers, which is correct.

But problem arises when i have otherUsers array with object(means atleast 1 other user found), my currentUser object is also present on the last index of otherUsers.[{1 other user object}, {currentUser object}]

I have checked on server side ,I am not sending currentUser in otherUsers.

I have tried to send static data of currentUser and otherUsers from server but i always receive it correctly.

Temporary or permanent solution which i used is to emit separate sockets of currentUser and otherUsers which works fine.

But i want to know why currentUser object is present at last index of otherUsers.

```
var foundUsers={
currentUser:{},
otherUsers:[]};



var getFixture = function(fixture,id){
if(fixture.GetBody().GetUserData() !== null && fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().type !== null ){
    if(fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().type=="player"){

        if(id==fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().id){
            foundUsers.currentUser={    
                    id : fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().id,
                    name : fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().name,
                    health: fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().health,
                    pos: fixture.GetBody().GetPosition(),
                    angle:fixture.GetBody().GetAngle(),
                    powerUps:fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().powerUps,
                }; 

        }else{
            foundUsers.otherUsers.push(
                {
                    id : fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().id,
                    name : fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().name,
                    health: fixture.GetBody().GetUserData().health,
                    pos: fixture.GetBody().GetPosition(),
                    angle:fixture.GetBody().GetAngle(),
                };
            );

        }

    }
}
return true;};

for (let u of users){//for loop iterating over all users

world.QueryAABB( getFixture , aabb , u.id );    

u.socket.emit('start',foundUsers.currentUser,foundUsers.otherUsers);

//resetting foundUsers
foundUsers={
    currentUser:{},
    otherUsers:[]
};}
```

Comment: without code, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: You probably have a shared object reference. Show the code that creates `currentUser` and `otherUsers`.